# Can't access variable (array) from another function (defined in global scope)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, variables

I'd like to use a variable (array) from another function. I already defined it in global scope, but it doesn't work..

Here is my code for better understanding:

```
var globalData = '';
var data = '';

$.getJSON('https://...' + data[x].id + '.json', function(data) {

    globalData = data;                                  
    data = globalData.name;

    console.log(data); // works just fine                                   

    if (condition === 1) {
        function2(); // calls this function
    } else {
        function3();
    }
});

function function2() {
    console.log(data); // just an empty line
    console.log(globalData); // UPDATE: works just fine
}
```

Comment: While my very first thought was that this was an async issue, I don't see that it is - `function2` is indeed called inside the callback. I think the problem is due to the shadowing of the `data` variable

Comment: @Tony - the OP DOES call the function within the callback.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thanks for you response. How can I solve this in my example?

Comment: This is not an asynchronous problem. I'm going to reask and answer the question for you.

Comment: @TomMaximilianMüller see the answer given by Maheer below - as I said, it's just a naming issue.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thank you very much! I would give you an upvote if I could :).

Comment: `function(data) {` <-- data != global data.... same variable name, hence why the different  variable name works.

Comment: @RandyCasburn One more question :). I passed data to the function like this: `function2(data)` and could only access if I did `function function2(data) { ... }`. Is this the correct way?

Comment: I voted to reopen - but that DOES NOT get the OP the answer they need.

Comment: I have no idea what that means or why it is the case without code. Please open a different question.

Comment: FWIW I'm casting a close vote as "too broad", as I can't flag as a dupe of the other question. The fact that you can't provide an answer to the other asked is irrelevant — you need to wait for it to be (potentially) reopened.

Comment: That's your prerogative. Thanks for taking time to explain your position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the variable `data` is being shadowed within the callback function.

```
function(data) {

    globalData = data;                                  
    data = globalData.name;

    console.log(data); // works just fine  
...
```

So `function(data)` established a local variable scoped to the function. Then the bizarre assign and reassign thing happens. You want to believe you are manipulating the global version of `data` but you are only dealing with the scoped version.

So, the variable `data` must be passed to the function.

If you prefer to use the global (not recommended), all you have to do is change the function declaration from `(data)` to some other identifier.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have two variables with name `data` one is local to call back and other is global. So when the following line

```
data = globalData.name;
```

doesn't change the global variable it just changes the local variable.

One solution is to have different name for global variable.

```
var globalData = '';
var data2 = '';

$.getJSON('https://...' + data[x].id + '.json', function(data) {

    globalData = data;                                  
    data2 = globalData.name;

    console.log(data2); // works just fine                                   

    if (condition === 1) {
        function2(); // calls this function
    } else {
        function3();
    }
});

function function2() {
    console.log(data2); // just an empty line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same variable name for two different things. You have a variable named `data` in your global scope and the `getJSON` callback function parameter also has a parameter called `data` which hides the `data` global variable. Also, inside that callback, you are modifying the `data` variable. If you intend to modify the `data` passed as parameter, this is not a good practice.