# Global scoped variable not accessible

Tags: javascript

**NOTE:** this is not an async problem. [This question was closed prematurely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56400495/cant-access-variable-array-from-another-function-defined-in-global-scope). I am reposting and answering so the OP has an answer that is useful.

I'd like to use a variable (array) from another function. I already defined it in global scope, but it doesn't work..

Here is my code for better understanding:

```
var globalData = '';
var data = '';

$.getJSON('https://...' + data[x].id + '.json', function(data) {

    globalData = data;                                  
    data = globalData.name;

    console.log(data); // works just fine                                   

    if (condition === 1) {
        function2(); // calls this function
    } else {
        function3();
    }
});

function function2() {
    console.log(data); // just an empty line
    console.log(globalData); // UPDATE: works just fine
}
```

Comment: right...just trying to help the OP from a diff question that was marked duplicate incorrectly. [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56400495/cant-access-variable-array-from-another-function-defined-in-global-scope). If you downvoted me, please reconsider as I'm only attempting to help the OP.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Reopen votes are a thing. You're intentionally posting a duplicate.